# Reading any well-formed RSS/ATOM file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, atom-feed

I want to be able to read any well-formed RSS/ATOM file.  That would mean I would not not know the tags, start the loop and the fields.  How do I go about doing it in PHP.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Do you want to read any random *well-formed* RSS/ATOM file?

Comment: Technically correct words. Yes thats what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Zend Framework's feed class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html).

But you should be more specific about your task..

Comment: I want to be able to do it from scratch without the assistance of any frameworks, would it be possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible :) If you say that you want to read well formated rss/atom feed, first what you want to do is examine rss/atom specifications ( http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html / http://www.rss-specifications.com/ / http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/atom-format-spec.php ) and then write your own class/parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleXML http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php